# Running delayed_jobs with daemon

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, daemon, delayed-job

I have paperclip setup with the delayed_jobs and daemon gem to process my images in the background. The issue I'm having is that I keep having to call `worker: rake jobs:work` manually in it's own terminal instance to process the queue. I can't seem to get daemon working.

procfile:

```
web: bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb
worker: rake jobs:work
```

bin/delayed_job:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require File.expand_path(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '..', 'config', 'environment'))
require 'delayed/command'
Delayed::Command.new(ARGV).daemonize
```

The [instructions](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job#running-jobs) say I can do the following: `RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job start`

but I'm not sure if that's telling me to add this line to the delayed_job.rb file or to run that command manually. Right now, jobs are just accumulating in heroku.

Comment: Can you check in the Heroku dashboard that the worker dyno is enabled ?

Comment: Oooh so I have  to  turn  it on in  heroku. Now it  will run fine?

Comment: Yes, it should run without any problems.

Comment: thank you, would never have found that